# User page weirdness for users without questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

A look at the following user pages:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/users/630
- https://math.stackexchange.com/users/642
- https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2820

shows that the CSS does something peculiar whenever the user has no questions asked on the site. Is this intentional behavior?

Comment: At a glance, I'm not seeing what's wrong—could you give a more specific description of what's wrong or post a screenshot with the problem marked/highlighted?

Comment: Here's the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/3UiIu.png) I posted in another thread; note that the "0 questions" is rather uncomfortably squished by the answers.

Comment: I can report that on safari, I'm not seeing this weird behavior. Questions is at the top above the Answers without the squishing.

Comment: Reproducible on Firefox 4 (beta browser), not reproducible on IE 8. Someone with Firefox 3.x should check.

Comment: Yes, happens in FF 3.6.9 at least.

Comment: Also in FF 3.6.11

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, I'm on Opera 10.61 build 6430.

Comment: Same problem on Opera 10.63 build 6450 on Linux.

Comment: Konqueror, OTOH, has no problem (which is expected, as Safari also has no problem).

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this. The change will be in the next deployment.